# Bigquery Schedule query to load data to a particular partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the bigquery schedule query functionality to run a query every 30 mins.
My destination table will be a partitioned table and the partionining column is `'event_date'`

The schedule query that i am using will be to copy today's data from `source_table -> Dest_table`
(like `select * from source_table where event_date = CURRENT_DATE()`)
every 30 mins , 
but i would like it to write_truncate existing partition without write truncating the whole table.(since i don't want to duplicate today's data every 30 mins)

Currently when i schedule this query with `partition_field` set to `event_date` and `write_truncate` , it is truncating the whole table and this causes the previous data to be lost . Is there something else that i am missing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying destination table, you may use MERGE to truncate only one partition.

It is unfortunately more expensive, for you also pay for deleting the data from dest_table. (Insert is still free)

```
MERGE dest_table t
USING source_table
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND event_date=CURRENT_DATE() THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
```